# Seeking a distribution, perhaps uncommon, consistent with two data points and expert constraints?

Tags: r, distributions, probability, bayesian, optimization

I am trying to state a prior distribution for a Bayesian meta-analysis.

I have the following information about a random variable:

1. Two observations: 3.0, 3.6
2. a scientist who studies the variable has told me that $P(X<2)=P(X>8)=0$, and that values as high as 6 have nonzero probability.

I have used the following approach to optimization (the mode of log-N = $e^{\mu-\sigma^2)}$:

```
prior <- function(parms, x, alpha) {
  a <- abs(plnorm(x[1], parms[1], parms[2]) - (alpha/2))
  b <- abs(plnorm(x[2], parms[1], parms[2]) - (1-alpha/2))
  mode <- exp(parms[1] - parms[2]^2)
  c <- abs(mode-3.3)
  return(a + b + c)
}
v = nlm(prior,c(log(3.3),0.14),alpha=0.05,x=c(2.5,7.5))
x <- seq(1,10,0.1)
plot(x, dlnorm(x, v$estimate[1], v$estimate[2]))
abline(v=c(2.5,7.5), lty=2) #95%CI
```

[image]

In the figure, you can see the distribution that this returns, but I would like to find something more like the red lines I have drawn in.

This provides the same shaped distribution using the lognormal, gamma, or the normal, and it results in a distribution with $P(X=5)<0.05$ and $P(X=6)< 0.01$, i.e.:

```
 plnorm(c(5,6), v$estimate[1],v$estimate[2])
```

Can anyone suggest alternatives? I would prefer to stick with a single distribution rather than a mixture.

Thanks!

Comment: In your question you have $P(X = 2) = 0$ and $P(X = 8) = 0$.  Do you mean: $P(X < 2) = 0$ and $P(X > 8) = 0$??

Comment: @M. Tibbits: yes, sorry for the error.

Comment: @David After reading this question over many, many times I still don't understand it.  Are you using the two observations and the scientist's opinion to estimate a prior for a Bayesian analysis?  Is your prior going to be based on the scientist's opinion only and then you want to update it with the observations?  What is the distinction between "unsurprising" and having zero probability?

Comment: @whuber I was originally trying to state the prior using the expert opinion and two data points by summarizing the two data points as a central tendency. But the idea of setting a prior with the expert opinion and updating it with may be a better idea since this approach does not rely on my own choice of a measure of central tendency. "Unsurprising" can be interpreted as "small but nonzero probability", e.g. $P(X>5)<0.05$ and $P(X>6)<0.01$

Comment: @David Why not just use a "maximally uninformative" prior or even a uniform prior then?  (Both are scaled beta distributions.)  You could even fit a maximal entropy solution to the expert opinion information (although I would be disinclined to do that, given that experts notoriously mis-estimate probabilities).

Comment: @whuber I'd like to stay away from the uninformed priors, and my question to the scientist attempted to take into account the difficulty of estimating probabilities, for example by following "what is your 95%CI" by "What values of X are inconceivable?" and "What values of X are conceivable but unlikely" as well as "Is X=6 at all possible, even if you would not expect to see it?". I tried to summarize this information in the question. I want to be conservative but not exclude available information.

Comment: @David I appreciate your care in eliciting the information.  But assigning specific values of 0.05 and 0.01 to those probabilities is questionable.  That's not your fault; it's just how things are.  We can't expect people to pin down probabilities that well (that's what data are for).  Maybe you would like to represent those with hyperpriors :-)?

Comment: @whuber thanks for the suggestion, I can't justify hyperpriors, but it would be sufficient to inflate the variance and overestimate the probabilities in the tails; isn't this done by giving an upper bound rather than an exact value, e.g., to $P(X=5) < 0.05$ ?

Comment: @David I don't see how an upper bound allows you to determine the distribution unless you specify an objective function to be optimized subject to that upper bound as a constraint.  For example, you might want to maximize the variance or the entropy subject to these constraints.  (The latter has more justification.)  Until you provide such a criterion, there seems to be no basis to choose among the many distributional forms suggested by existing responses.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for following up. Now I understand the concept of the maximum entropy solution that you previously suggested, although it would require some learning on my end before I would want to apply it. Your alternative, maximizing variance, sounds sufficiently consistent with my objective and straightforward for me to implement. Thanks again.

Comment: @David Be aware that a problem with maximizing variance is that the solution will be a discrete distribution.  I expect it to concentrate 0.01 probability at X=8, 0.04 at X=6, 157/300 at X=2, and the rest (32/75) at X=5.  (This variance equals 2.59.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If, given an answer to my comment above, you wish to bound the range of the distribution, why not simply fit a Beta distribution where you rescale to the unit interval?  In other words, if you know that the parameter of interest should fall between $[2 , 8]$, then why not define $Y = \frac{X - 5}{6} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{X - 2}{6}$.  Where I've first centered the interval on zero, divided by the width so that Y will have a range of 1, and then added $\frac{1}{2}$ back so that the range of Y is $[0,1]$. (You can think of it either way: directly from $[2,8] \rightarrow [0,1]$ or from $[2,8] \rightarrow [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] \rightarrow [0,1]$, but I thought the latter might be easier at first).

Then, with two data points, you could fit a beta posterior with a uniform beta prior?

Answer (score 7):

What about the [Kumaraswamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution) distribution, which has the following pdf:

$$
f(x; a,b) = a b x^{a-1}{ (1-x^a)}^{b-1} 
$$
for $a>0$, $b>0$, $0 < x < 1$. This distribution can be [rescaled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution#Generalizing_to_arbitrary_range) to have the required support.

Answer (score 7):

You could also try the triangular distribution.  To fit this, you basically specify a lower bound (this would be X=2), an upper bound (this would be X=8), and a "most likely" value.  The wikepedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution has more info on this distribution.  If there is not much faith in the "most likely" value (as it appears to be, prior to observing any data), it may be a good idea to place a non-informative prior distribution on it, and then use the two data points to estimate this value.  One good one is the jeffrey's prior, which for this problem would be p(c) = 1/(pi*sqrt((c-2)*(c-8))), where "c" is the "most likely value" (consistent with the wikipedia notation).

Given this prior, you can work out the posterior distribution of c analytically, or via simulation.  The analytic form of the likelihood is not particularly nice, so simulation seems to be more attractive.  This example is particularly well suited to rejection sampling (see wiki page for a general description of rejection sampling), because the maximised likelihood is 1/3^n regardless of the value of c, which provides the "upper bound".  So you generate a "candidate" from the jeffrey's prior (call it c_i), and then evaluate the likelihood at this candidate L(x1,..,xn|c_i), and divide by the maximised likelihood, to give (3^n)*L(x1,..,xn|c_i).  You then generate a U(0,1) random variable, and if u is less than (3^n)*L(x1,..,xn|c_i), then accept c_i as a posterior sampled value, otherwise throw away c_i and start again.  Repeat this process until you have enough accepted samples (100, 500, 1,000, or more depending on how accurate you want).  Then just take the sample average of whatever function of c you are interested in (the likelihood of a new observation is an obvious candidate for your application).

An alternative to accept-reject is to use the value of the likelihood as a weight (and don't generate the u), and then proceed with taking weighted averages using all candidates, rather than un-weighted averages with the accepted candidates

Answer (score 6):

Since the log-normal distribution has two parameters, you can't satisfactorily fit it to three constraints that don't naturally fit it. With extreme quantiles of 2.5 and 7.5, the mode is ~4, and there is not much you can do about it. Since the scale of the errors for `a` and `b` is much smaller than for `c`, one of them will be pretty much ignored during the optimization.

For a better fit, you can either pick a three-parameter distribution, for example the generalized gamma distribution (implemented in the `VGAM` package), or add a shift parameter to the lognormal (or gamma, ...) distribution.

As a last note, since the distribution you are looking for is clearly not symmetric, the average of the two given observations is not the right value for the mode. I would  maximize the sum of the densities at 3.0 and 3.6 while maintaining the extreme quantiles at 2.5 and 7.5 - this is possible if you have three parameters.